# database exposed to internet

Tags: database, web-services, web

I'm new to a company. I'm put in charge of a performance tracking system. So let me introduce the structure to you. First, the api server(living in China) accept the performance data by using restful API. Next, this api server forward these data to an inter-API Server(living in Singapore). Finally, the inter-api server located in Singapore save those data to database(amazon RDS in Singapore).

I was thinking that inter-API Server which living in Singapore is not necessary. Their original concern for this design was security. They didn't want their DB exposed to internet. But I suppose it might have easy way to do this. Don't have to develop an inter-API Server only for this purpose. I don't want that inter-API Server existed over there. So I'd like to ask some solutions which are easier for this security purpose. Please share them if you have some ideas about this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Which will take more time writing the API or explaining to clients, customers and bosses why protecting their data didn't seem important at the time?

Comment: Sorry - practical advice, can you lock down the DB by IP address? Even if you can I'd still lean towards the "do it properly" approach